# How to use date time as a cluster in where clause in Cassandra using python driver?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I am using python driver and Cassandra, I have created the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE channelFollowers(
    channelID BIGINT,
    isfavorite BOOLEAN,                     
    userID BIGINT,                                                          
    followDate TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID, channelID, followDate)
);
```

my question is, how can i use the `followDate` in where clause of select and update query, I have tried but it does not work it gives the following error

```
typeerror: not enough arguments for format string
```

can any body help me please?

Here is my code
`channelLike = channelSession.execute("update channelfollowers set isblocked=%s, isfavorite=%s where userid=%s and channelid=%s and followdate=%s",[int(userid),int(channel_id),followDate]`

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the error message & in your code - you have 5 placeholders in format string (`%s`), but pass only 3 values. I believe that you omit placeholders for `isblocked` & `isfavorite` parameters - either pass them, or replace `%s` with true/false values (as I can see from query, they should have boolean type)

P.S. you also don't have `isblocked` in the table's definition